Reason for whirls and vortices when pouring milk in tea: Which hydrodynamic instabilities are relevant?
When pouring milk into tea or coffee, one can readily observe finger-like structures with whirls and vortices evolving as the milk flows into the tea or coffee.
See e.g. this image.
I'm searching for the cause of this hydrodynamic phenomenon.
In the internet I can find surprisingly few information about this. In the German wikipedia page about the Rayleigh-Taylor instability, it is written that this is the reason for the appearance of milk in tea. However, I don't see a reason why the Kelvin-Helmholtz instability should not be relevant in this context, too. The Kelvin-Helmholtz instability occurs if velocity gradients are present, which is the case if milk is poured into tea.
My questions are:
Which instabilities (Rayleigh-Taylor vs. Kelvin-Helmholtz) are governing the visually observable behaviour of the flow patterns, and why? Which instability has the strongest influence? Which one is less influential, and why?

The English version of the RTI page says, "When the two layers of the fluid are allowed to have a relative velocity, the instability is generalized to the Kelvin–Helmholtz–Rayleigh–Taylor instability, which includes both the Kelvin–Helmholtz instability and the Rayleigh–Taylor instability as special cases". So looks like the answer to which instability governs this is "both"

Thank you for pointing this out.
